# cast class to template class

Tags: c++, templates, casting, operators

I have a small project i'm doing on c++.
The project requires me to write a template class, let's say class A.
I have few requirements on A, among them:

1. No dynamic allocation is allowed in A implementation.
2. A holds a parameter of type T (not a pointer, so no "new").
3. A can be empty (i.e. it was not initialized).
4. One can initialize A in those following ways:

   ```
   A<int> a;
   A<int> a(5);
   A<int> a = 5;
   A<int> a = Empty;
   ```

I have no problem with the 3 first types of initialization, however I am a bit clueless regarding the last option.

Empty is some class that I should define however I want. My original direction was to create an (empty) class EmptyClass:

```
class EmptyClass {};
```

statically instantiate an object named Empty (so any used of class A will also know Empty):

```
static EmptyClass Empty;
```

and that's it. Apparently, it doesn't work.

The entire (relevant) template declaration:

```
class A{
private:
    T _Value;
    bool _empty;
public:
    A();
    A(const T value);
    A(const EmptyClass none);
    A(const A& opt);
    A(const EmptyClass & none);
    //Checks if the object is empty
    const bool isEmpty() const;
    //Destructor
    ~Optional();
    A<T>& operator=(const EmptyClass& rhs);
    A<T>& operator=(const A<T>& rhs);
};
```

Currently I'm getting an error in this line:

```
A<int> optionalInt = Empty
```

The error is:

> error: invalid conversion from 'EmptyClass (*)()' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

i am allowed to use only c++98 standard.
Would like to get any direction for solving this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show the entire template class declaration.

Comment: You might want to learn about [Boost optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) (which will be introduced in the C++17 standard as [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)). If you don't want to use that, then at least you could use it as a reference for creating your own optional class.

Comment: As for the problem you're asking about, please edit the question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or at the very least show us the declaration of `Empty`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Edited my original post, I hope that now it's good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

You have two constructors that can take an `EmptyClass` as input.

```
A(const EmptyClass none);
A(const EmptyClass & none);
```

Both are equally good candidates for the line

```
A<int> a = Empty;
```

The compiler is not able to disambiguate the constructor to be used.

The simple fix is to remove one of them. I suggest that you remove the first of those two constructors.

**Problem 2:**

This is a very strange line you have.

```
~Optional();
```

That needs to be:

```
~A();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. This was pretty much the problem. I also added a casting operator to the "none" class. The optional is something I forgot to change from my implementation to the simplified "model" here.